# A few stupid questions about Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans-7

Is anybody use Eclipse IDE for Java EE Development? If somebody does, can you answer me for this questions?

1. How to create files like "beans.xml", "sun-web.xml" and so on. Some XML's is created during the project creation process, but there is no special templates for creating others. I think, I should create "XML file" and write apropriate name and contents by hand. Am I right? NetBeans has much more templates, I think.
2. After using of NetBeans, It's hard for me to understand the principes of libraries configuration in the "Java Build Path" properties. If I use GlassFish or JBoss - should I use "Mojarra" or "MyFaces" JSF implementation as User libraries? I think, in the case of GlassFish - I am not, cos the Application server already have this libraries.
3. What book(s) you recomend me to read for finding answers for my stupid questions? I try to read help center in the eclipse.org, but there are mostly ready to use examples with no answers.

P.S. I use Juno release of Eclipse and seems like it's better works with GF 3.1.2 and JBoss AS 7.1 than NetBeans 7.2. That's why I am interesting Eclipse IDE for EE development.

Thank you for helping me and wasting your time.

Comment: Please limit your questions to one per post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is specific from glassfish, so eclipse won't generate them by default. These will be probably generated if you install [Eclipse Glassfish plugin](http://glassfishplugins.java.net/)
2. Even if the application server has these libraries, you should add them to the build path so eclipse knows what to use when compiling it. If you are working with glassfish, in the libraries tab on the build path options, click add library -> Server runtime -> Glassfish (You will have to install glassfish plugin before)
3. I believe you can find most of these answers on internet, I've been developing with eclipse for +5 years, and never checked a book.

Comment: Thanks. I have Glassfish Server Adapter installed on my Eclipse IDE, and Glassfish's runtime in the list of libraries. The same I can tell about JBoss. Plugins in your link seems to be old, and probably do the same things in the older Eclipse IDE releases.